# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el color del fondo sin que las letras no desaparezcan en CSS?

Tags: html, css

Soy bastante nuevo en el desarrollo web y estoy tratando de colocar un fondo negro, pero cuando lo intento, las letras desaparecen.

Puse este segmento de código que aprendí, pero cuando lo pongo, todo el contenido desaparece sin rastro:

```
  body {
      background-color: black;
    }
```

Eh intentado cambiar a colores menos opacos, pero no ah funcionado.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el resto de tu código por favor?, aunque con un `color: white;` debería alcanzar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Has intentado cambiar el color del texto? Probablemente el texto está ahí pero no puedes verlo porque su color sigue siendo negro

```
  body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```